# OpenShift: Restart pod on out-of-memory exception

Tags: kotlin, kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift

I have a pod running in OpenShift. The pod runs a Kafka consumer continously polling on a topic and storing the records locally for a given time. Sporadically, the topic will get a large burst of new records. This will cause an OOM exception due to the memory space needed to store the records. However, this is fine, as it is okay for the pod to just restart and consume again.

The problem, though, is that the pod does not restart on OOM exceptions. After the pod crashes, the health endpoint (server) is still active. As a result, the pod will not restart, since OpenShift still thinks the pod is healthy. From the log messages, it looks like the `shutdownHook` is never run.

My health endpoint service is implemented as

```kotlin
class HealthService : ILogging by Logging<HealthService>() {

    @Get("/health")
    fun health(): HttpResponse {
        log.trace("I'm $responseText")
        return HttpResponse.of(
            statusCode,
            MediaType.PLAIN_TEXT_UTF_8,
            responseText
        )
    }

    /**
     * Should be called when the graceful shutdown process is completed. The service will now be
     * considered dead by Kubernetes and the pod will be restarted.
     */
    fun die() {
        log.trace("Last breath...")
        health.set(DEAD)
    }

    /** Thread-safe health state. */
    private val health: AtomicInteger = AtomicInteger(ALIVE)

    private val responseText
        get() =
            when (health.get()) {
                ALIVE -> "alive"
                SICK -> "sick"
                else -> "dead"
            }

    private val statusCode
        get() =
            when (health.get()) {
                DEAD -> HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
                else -> HttpStatus.OK
            }

    companion object {
        const val ALIVE = 0
        const val SICK = 1
        const val DEAD = 2
    }
}
```

and my main application is implemented as

```kotlin
val log = Logger()
lateinit var healthService: HealthService

fun run() {
        val consumer = createKafkaConsumer()

        val server = buildServer(log)
        val future = server.start()
        future.join()

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            Thread {
                log.info("Closing down...")
                server.close()
                healthService.die()
            }
        )
        consumer.run()
    }

private fun buildServer(log: Logger): Server {
        log.info("Loading HTTP Endpoints on port ${config.port}...")
        val sb = Server.builder().http(config.port).service(
            "/"
        ) { _, _ -> HttpResponse.of("OK\n") }

        healthService = HealthService()
        sb.annotatedService(healthService)

        return sb.build()
    }
```

The Kafka consumer is simply implemented as

```kotlin
class Consumer() {

    val cache = Cache()
    val name = "myConsumer"
 

    fun run() {
        try {
            val pollDuration = config.kafka.pollDurationSeconds

            while (true) {
                val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(pollDuration))
                addToCache(records)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error("Unexpected event happened. e=$e", e)
        } finally {
            log.info("Closing down $name consumer...")
            consumer.close()
            cache.close()
        }
    }
```

To summarize, an OOM exception is thrown in `consumer.run()` making the program crash. The health endpoint, however, continues to run. Therefore, OpenShift still thinks the program/pod and the pod will not be restarted.

How can I kill the health endpoint when an OOM exception is thrown in `consumer.run()`?

EDIT: Add Kubernetes configuration

```yaml
...
readiness:
    path: /health
liveness:
    path: /health
....
```

Answer (score 0):

When your consumer or application goes out of memory at that time ideally even your **health endpoint** should stop giving **204** or **200** responses.

From the Kubernetes side, you have to use the **Liveness** to monitor this endpoint.

Liveness will auto restart the application as soon as your application gets stopped and not returning the **200** or **204** to K8s.

Here liveness probe YAML example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: <Docker image>
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

this will check **/tmp/healthy** endpoint on every **5** second of the period.

Comment: I added part of my Kubernetes config. I have set up `liveness`  to check the `health/` endpoint exposed by the `HealthService`. The problem is that this endpoint is still exposed after an exception is thrown in `consumer.run()`. It does not look like the shutdown hook kills the `HealthService`.

Comment: yes right, that's the issue checking code health one not getting shutdown.